# iPhone app questionary, aks a different question every day

Tags: iphone

I am developing a  questionary app, I want to store a lot of questions and make the app capable to ask me a diferent question every day, and if the  question was already asked, go to the next question, I mean, diferent questions, every time the app is loaded, but I can't  make it work, also want the app permit to take only one question per day, I appreciate your help... I am stuck here.

Answer (score 0):

It will be necessary to store, for each question, the "already asked status". So if your questions are stored in a text file, add a delimiter and then a symbol to indicate the question has been asked. Then, every time you open the questions file, keep skipping down until you find a question that has not been marked "already asked".
For your second requirement, you'll need to store somewhere the date of most-recent asking. Consider putting this in the question file as well (assuming you are indeed using a file) as a third datum for each question. Then you will have a "historical timeline" of question askings.

Comment: Should I Make A Text File For Every Single Question?

Comment: Sorry, just noticed the inbox feature, so a very late reply. You could do that, but I think having one big file for all questions would be better and more safe with respect to limitations of a filesystem & filesystem API. Try this: have all the questions, one per line in one file. Then have an answers file where each line corresponds to the same line in the question file. Each line of the answer file could be a date and status (correct,incorrect,deferred).